# jQuery, selectable and text-align property issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I can't center string inside table row during selecting item.

I try use JQuery events with .css method, but it not working.

Any idea for repair it?

Thanks in advance!

**Before select:**

[image: Before selectable]

**During selecting:**

[image: During selectable]

**JQuery:**

```
$('.flex-container').sortable({
    axis: 'z',
    revert: true,
    forcePlaceholderSize: true,
    handle: '.move',
}).disableSelection();
```

**CSS:**

```
th, tr {text-align: center;}
```

Comment: Share your code please

Comment: Table is default bootstrap 4 table > https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/content/tables/

Comment: I updated css and jquery code.

Answer (score 3):

We can't help much without looking at the code. But just assuming you are using bootstrap.css you can use `text-center` class in your table cell.

```
<asp:tablecell runat="server" cssclass="text-center"></asp:tablecell>
```

Comment: Did my answer helped you or you are looking for something else?

Comment: Have you applied classes inside your table like:- <table class="table col-lg-12">.......</table>

Comment: I did not do that.

Comment: But I do not need bootrap grid system. Code: https://pastebin.com/HmDszCuK

Comment: Its issue with selectable event.